# How do I `select` over execution target?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have the following rule but it isn't working because the `select` is evaluating `target platform` instead of  `host platform` or `execution platform`.

Does anyone know how to make it work?

```
cargo_build_script(
    name = "build_script",
    srcs = ["build.rs"],
    build_script_env = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_aarch64": {
            "PROTOC": "$(execpath @com_google_protobuf_protoc_linux_aarch64//:protoc)",
            "RUSTFMT": "$(execpath @rust_linux_aarch64//:rustfmt_bin)",
        },
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": {
            "PROTOC": "$(execpath @com_google_protobuf_protoc_linux_x86_64//:protoc)",
            "RUSTFMT": "$(execpath @rust_linux_x86_64//:rustfmt_bin)",
        },
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin_arm64": {
            "PROTOC": "$(execpath @com_google_protobuf_protoc_macos_aarch64//:protoc)",
            "RUSTFMT": "$(execpath @rust_darwin_aarch64//:rustfmt_bin)",
        },
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin_x86_64": {
            "PROTOC": "$(execpath @com_google_protobuf_protoc_macos_x86_64//:protoc)",
            "RUSTFMT": "$(execpath @rust_darwin_x86_64//:rustfmt_bin)",
        },
    }),
    crate_features = [
        "transport",
    ],
    data = [
        "//api/protos:protos",
        "@com_google_protobuf//:protoc",
        "@com_google_protobuf//:well_known_protos",
    ] + select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_aarch64": [
            "@rust_linux_aarch64//:rustfmt_bin",
            "@com_google_protobuf_protoc_linux_aarch64//:protoc",
        ],
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": [
            "@rust_linux_x86_64//:rustfmt_bin",
            "@com_google_protobuf_protoc_linux_x86_64//:protoc",
        ],
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin_arm64": [
            "@rust_darwin_aarch64//:rustfmt_bin",
            "@com_google_protobuf_protoc_macos_aarch64//:protoc",
        ],
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin_x86_64": [
            "@rust_darwin_x86_64//:rustfmt_bin",
            "@com_google_protobuf_protoc_macos_x86_64//:protoc",
        ],
    }),
    deps = [
        "@raze__tonic_build__0_6_2//:tonic_build",
    ],
)
```

I know there is an `exex_compatible_with` option for each rule but this doesn't help. I would have to create one rule per `execution platform` but then select again each rule given the platform.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I solve it with:

```
cargo_build_script(
    name = "build_script",
    srcs = ["build.rs"],
    build_script_env = {
        "PROTOC": "$(execpath @com_google_protobuf//:protoc)",
        "RUSTFMT": "$(rootpath @rules_rust//rust/toolchain:current_rustfmt_files)",
    },
    crate_features = [
        "transport",
    ],
    data = [
        "//api/protos",
        "@com_google_protobuf//:well_known_protos",
        "@rules_rust//rust/toolchain:current_rustfmt_files",
    ],
    tools = [
        "@com_google_protobuf//:protoc",
    ],
    deps = all_crate_deps(
        normal = True,
        normal_dev = True,
    ),
)
```

Execution platform is handle inside the rule.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).